# add view above tabwidget tabs

Tags: android, android-layout

How add view (linearlayout with textview for example) above tabs in FragmentTabHost?

I need to put view between ActionBar and TabWidget. I tried add margin to tabwidget, but it only adds margin to the tab content.

Here is my xml code:

```
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/tabhost">
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:orientation="horizontal"
                  android:id="@+id/paneLocation"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="123123"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <TabWidget
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_below="@id/paneLocation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
            />
    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabFrameLayout"
            android:layout_below="@id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />
    <ProgressBar android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:id="@+id/pbLoading"
                 android:visibility="invisible"
                 android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            />
</RelativeLayout>
```

TextView now overlays tabs, instead of appearing above it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:background="#fff">
    <TextView android:text="desired view"
        />
    <android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#c9c9c9"
        android:id="@+id/tabhost">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            />
    </android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```